# What's the difference between DI_ICON1 and IDI_ICON1?

Tags: windows, rc

I'm working on a Windows app that needs to run on XP, Vista, 7, and 8. I'm trying to set the application icon, and it works, using DI_ICON1 as the tag in my RC file:

```
DI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "myapp.ico"
```

Using IDI_ICON1 didn't seem to do the right thing here.

However, I also create a second window (also at the root level, ie not a child of my app's main window) and the ALT-TAB icon for that second window wasn't showing up correctly; it was just the default, generic app icon. Adding a *second* line to the RC now made the ALT-TAB icon work:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "myapp.ico"
```

so with both lines everything works. But I don't know why or how or wtf these identifiers even mean. So what are they, where are they defined, and by what magic do they work?

Comment: Those are just arbitrary identifiers from `resource.h`. There must be some code which uses those identifiers somewhere.

Comment: Why use one or the other? Is there some standard definition of the two values?

Answer (score 1):

`IDI_ICON1` is just a unique name identifying the resource. You can give it any name as long as it is unique. The development environment should generate a `Resource.h` file that uses a `#define` preprocessor directive to assign it a 16-bit unsigned integer unique identifier.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/icon-resource
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=msvc-170

`IDI_ICON1` is probably just a convention that someone came up with, where `IDI` means "ID Icon", and 1 is because it is the first icon being defined. So, if you were defining another icon you'd identify it with `IDI_ICON2`. If you were defining a bitmap resource, you would identify it with `IDB_BITMAP1`.

`DISCARDEABLE` is only relevant for 16-bit Windows. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/common-resource-attributes